# Python - Grouping by multiple columns (Categorical dtype vs numeric dtype)- why are the results so different?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, multiple-columns

I have a question about grouping pandas DataFrames by multiple columns. I am looking at some data for a TV show and trying to ensure that no season has two contestants with the same name.

| Series | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | David |
| 1 | Edward |
| 1 | Jasmine |
| 2 | Lea |
| 2 | Jonathan |
| 2 | Louise |

I want a unique count for groupings of Series + Name, which works well when the Series contains a numeric data type. I can do:

```py
df.groupby(['Series','Name'])['Name'].count()
```

and get

| Series | Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | 1 |
| 1 | Edward | 1 |
| 1 | Jasmine | 1 |
| 2 | Lea | 1 |
| 2 | Jonathan | 1 |
| 2 | Louise | 1 |

However, if series is set to a categorical data type then

```py
df.groupby(['Series','Name'])['Name'].count()
```

returns the following table

| Series | Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | David | 1 |
| 2 | David | 0 |
| 1 | Edward | 1 |
| 2 | Edward | 0 |
| 1 | Jasmine | 1 |
| 2 | Jasmine | 0 |
| 1 | Jonathan | 0 |
| 2 | Jonathan | 1 |
| 1 | Lea | 0 |
| 2 | Lea | 1 |
| 1 | Louise | 0 |
| 2 | Louise | 1 |

Panda groups every possible combination of series and names and then sorts alphanumerically. I don't understand why. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: What is your desired output? Why are you comparing categorial vs. numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is the default behaviour of Pandas when grouping categorical value, it adds missing categories (checkout this [thread](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17594)).
To group only the observed categories on the dataframe you can use:

```
df.groupby(['Series','Name'],observed=True)['Name'].count()
```

Comment: Thanks! @anas laaroussi that was perfect!